# How do I call a variable in scenario SA of feature file FA from a scenario SB of a feature file FB?

Tags: java, cucumber, karate, bdd, gherkin

In Karate, I have following:
Feature file `FA` containing scenario `SA` and
Feature file `FB` containing scenario `SB`

String Variable `VA` is generated in scenario `SA`. From scenario `SB`, I would like to initialize a new string variable `VB` by calling the variable `VA` from scenario `SA`.
I don't know how to do that after researching.
Can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

First I can point you to an example: [Api calling in loop sending different id in url each time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72388146/143475)

Note how the variable `bookingid` is set in the second `Scenario`. Please spend time reading the docs here to understand how it works: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call

To make things even more clearer, here is another example:

```
Feature:

  Scenario: caller
    * def result = call read('@called')
    * match result.foo == 'bar'

  @called
  Scenario:
    * def foo = 'bar'
```