# In Scenario outline how to set the the limitation for reading the data from the csv files

Tags: karate

Consider the below example

Feature: scenario outline using a dynamic table
from a csv file

Scenario Outline: cat name: 
Given url demoBaseUrl
And path 'cats'
And request { name: '#(name)', age: '#(age)' }
When method post
Then status 200
And match response == { id: '#number', name: '#(name)' }

```
# the single cell can be any valid karate expression
# and even reference a variable defined in the Background
Examples:
| read('kittens.csv') |
```

If the above kittens.csv file contains 100 rows I want to read only 50 rows to execute the scenario outline .Is there any way in karate to ready only the given n rows from csv file

Answer (score 0):

Since it is pure JS, any `Array` operation is possible. So you can easily do this:

```
| read('kittens.csv').slice(0, 49) |
```

That said, Karate was not designed for this. You may be better off trying to do data-driven tests like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72388475/143475